# Why are react-table pagination, filter, and sort reset automatically when its (the react-table) data changes?

Tags: reactjs, sorting, filter, pagination, react-table

I added 4 custom columns to my table columns list using its `Cell` property; each of these columns in every row contains a checkbox that changes a specific property in the table's data state; its data state structure is something like so:

```js
export type dataTypes = {
    id: number;
    getAccess: boolean;
    insertAccess: boolean;
    editAccess: boolean;
    deleteAccess: boolean;
}[];
```

I don't want [react-table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/) (v7.7.0) pagination to reset to its first page when the table's data state is modified by the checkboxes (also about the table's filter and sort).

Does anyone know about it?

Comment: Hi. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding `autoResetPage: false`, `autoResetFilters: false`, and `autoResetSortBy: false` to `useTable` hook like so:

```js
const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns,
        data,
        autoResetPage: false,
        autoResetFilters: false,
        autoResetSortBy: false
    }, usePagination)
```

Comment: Thanks to Shyam Padia.

Comment: I lost hours for nothing. It makes no sense to reset by default.

Comment: There is `autoResetAll` in recent versions.